# Apache doesn't load GnuPG PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'm installed GnuPG via Pecl. Generate pub/priv keys etc.. I have in `php.ini`

```
extension=gnupg.so
```

When I try to run simple code I've got undefined gnupg_init() error which by my understands is meaning that module isn't loaded.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gnupg_init()
```

This is the code which I trying to run

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/stan/.gnupg');
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_seterrormode($res,GNUPG_ERROR_WARNING);
gnupg_addencryptkey($res,"myfingerprint");
$enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, "just a test");
echo $enc;
```

The system is ubuntu + apache.
Here are permissions of the `.gnupg/`

```
srwxrwxr-x 1 stan stan    0 Aug 16 08:12 S.gpg-agent
-rw------- 1 stan stan   32 Aug 16 10:02 pubring.kbx~
drwx------ 2 stan stan 4096 Aug 16 10:04 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stan stan 1361 Aug 16 10:04 pubring.kbx
drwx------ 2 stan stan 4096 Aug 16 10:04 openpgp-revocs.d
-rw------- 1 stan stan 2603 Aug 16 10:19 secring.gpg
-rw------- 1 stan stan 1209 Aug 16 10:19 pubring.gpg~
-rw------- 1 stan stan 1360 Aug 16 10:19 trustdb.gpg
-rw------- 1 stan stan  600 Aug 16 10:19 random_seed
-rw------- 1 stan stan 1209 Aug 16 10:19 pubring.gpg
```

Here is my /var/www/

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 stan www-data 4096 Jul 14 11:23 www
drwxr-sr-x 7 stan www-data 4096 Aug 16 09:59 html
```

I have also confirmation that is installed and loaded

```
$ php --info | grep gnupg
gnupg
gnupg support => enabled
```

Comment: Make sure you are editing the correct php.ini. Often command line and the webserver have different ini files. You can check which php.ini is in use using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Yes, I checked with `phpinfo();` and I'm sure that I've editing correct `php.ini`.

Comment: Did you restart your apache after editing the ini file?

Comment: Yes, multiple times...

Comment: On the terminal i've tried `~$ php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("gnupg_decrypt"));';` and I've got true which means it should work `bool(true)`

Comment: @Garg Did you ever solve this issue? Workaround?